# firing 2 shots at different angles, how to calculate a time such that both shots land at the same time and in the same location?)

Tags: calculus

I have the following information:

> > [image]

How can I solve for s and z?

I have been solving problems like this but have always been given the feet per second. Now that I don't have that, how do I get this value? I know I should be deriving since the rate of change is not given correct?

Answer (score 1):

So we will derive a position function for a cannonball fired at some inclination. I'm ignoring air resistance and assuming its just gravity acting on the ball after its fired, don't know anything about physics so if this isn't what you're looking for sorry. But it should still be instructive.

We know that $\textbf{F}= m\textbf{a}$ if we let the mass of the cannonball be $1$ and let $g$ denote the gravitational constant then. $F=-g\textbf{j}$. If we integrate this with respect to time $t$ then we get that. $\textbf{v}(t) = -gt\textbf{j} + \textbf{v}_0$ for some initial velocity $\textbf{v}_0$. It is given that $|\textbf{v}_0|=s$. So we have that: $$\textbf{v}_0=s* \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta + z) \\ \sin(\theta + z) \end{pmatrix}$$ We can then derive the position function with straightforward integration and noting that the intial position of the ball is $[0,0]^T$. This gives the position function $\textbf{p}(t)=\frac{-gt^2}{2}\textbf{j} +t\textbf{v}_0$.

Now we are interested in when the ball will hit the ground. In other words we want to know when the y component of $\textbf{p}$ is 0.

We have that $y=\frac{-gt^2}{2} + st[sin(\theta + z)] \rightarrow y=t[2s*(\sin(\theta +z)) - gt] $ and we can ignore the $0$ at $t=0$ as this is when the ball hasn't been fired. So we want to solve $2s*[\sin(\theta +z)] - gt = 0$ which gives- with $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$- that $t = \frac{\sqrt{2}s}{g}*[\cos(z)+\sin(z)]$. This gives the time as a function of $z$ it takes the ball to hit the ground.

Now if we solve a similar equation except we replace plus $z$ with minus $z$ then we will have the time it takes the second ball fired to hit the ground. Doing so gives us $t_0 =  \frac{\sqrt{2}s}{g}*[\cos(z) - \sin(z)]$

Finally we want that $t_2 + f(z) = t$. Solving this we find that $f(z) = 2*sin(z)$.